# How to make Intellij Idea start glassfish as sudo?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I am trying to run a glassfish local server from Intellij Idea and have some troubles. The server only wants to run from terminal via sudo command, and the Intellij runs by default without sudo, so how do I fix it? Do I have to make the file to always get executed as sudo(if yes, then how) or should I set in the Idea configs to run that specific file as sudo?

Answer (score 0):

All information consists in this guide: ["Run/Debug Configuration: GlassFish Server"](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-glassfish-server.html).

Comment: yeah but there's no word about my problem

Comment: There no mention in that link regarding running the server with super account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by unzipping this to my home directory and changed the location of glassfish inside idea to the new location.